# Remote access pc on usb 3G?

Tags: c#, sockets, network-programming

I develop a application remote desktop on c#. it' work good on ADSL with router add  NAT port.
but when i run on computer connect internet use usb modem 3g sim because usb modem not use connect like a ADLS (router), application not work. how i can connect pc use usb model? thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your 3G phone service provider puts you behind NAT then you're short of luck as the NAT prevents any incoming connections to reach your computer.

A workaround is to set up a VPN connection from your 3G-connected computer and set up port-forwarding at the VPN server-side, that way your computer can receive new connections, but they would be tunneled.

Comment: I also think set up VPN but it's need a static ip can operate stably.